# php inarray returns TRUE for the value ZERO

Tags: php

I am trying to use [in_array function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) and its returning TRUE if the value is ZERO. var_dump also returning **bool TRUE**

```
$srcElement=0;
var_dump(in_array($srcElement,array('HA','DA','SA','CA')));
if (in_array($srcElement,array('HA','DA','SA','CA')))
{
    echo "VALUE EXISTS";
}
else
{
 echo "VALUE NOT FOUND";   
}
```

and getting output as

```
bool(true) VALUE EXISTS
```

in case of **ZERO** if I use any other integers its returning ELSE PART.
is there any specific reason behind this ?

Comment: `var_dump(0 == 'HA');` Then check the 3rd argument of `in_array`

Comment: Use `strict` parameter for `in_array`

Comment: Also see the very first example and comment on the Manual page that you referred us to in your question

Comment: try `$srcElement='0';`

Comment: Gotcha :( I missed that parameter ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is type conversions, while doing the comparisons. Try with strict comparisons.

```
in_array($srcElement,array('HA','DA','SA','CA'),true);

var_dump(in_array($srcElement,array('HA','DA','SA','CA')));
```

will print `false`.